# Continuous random variable - coefficients and distributive function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Example:

Let $\xi$  - continuous random variable. Density function of this distribution is function:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
a(x-1), & x\in(1,2) \\[2ex]
b, & x\in[3,4) \\[2ex]
0, & else
\end{cases}
$

(a) Find constants a,b so that $P(\xi >3)=\frac{1}{4}$

(b) Find distribution function of random variable $\xi$

(c) Compute $P(\xi>2).$

My solution:

(a)

We know that: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad  \int_{1}^{2}a(x-1)\,dx\ + \int_{3}^{4}b\,dx\;=1$

and $\qquad\qquad\int_{3}^{4}b\,dx=\frac{1}{4}$

My result: $a=\frac{1}{2},\,b=\frac{1}{4}$

(b)

$F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(t)\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{2}(x-1)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}, & x\in(1,2) \\[2ex]
\int_{3}^{x} \frac{1}{4} \,dx = \frac{1}{4}x-\frac{3}{4}, & x\in[3,4) \\[2ex]
0, & else
\end{cases}
$

(c)

Shouldn't $P(\xi>2)$ be equal to $P(\xi>3)$?

Is my solution correct?

I am not sure, if I can use these two relations in example (a) to compute these constants.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Your value of $a$ seems to be incorrect, but you use correct relations.

(b) The distribution function is an increasing function such that $\lim_{t\to -\infty }F(t)=0$, $\lim_{t\to +\infty }F(t)=1$, which is not the case for your $F$. Again, the basic formula that you use is almost correct. The only untidy thing is that you use the same variable ($t$) as the integration variable and the upper integration limit. Your integration in the first line is definitely wrong.

(c) Yes, $P(\xi>2)=\int_2^{+\infty}f(x)\, dx$ by definition, but this integral is just the same as $\int_3^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx$, since your density is zero between $2$ and $3$.